# Poor rendering quality on Android's WebView

Tags: android, css, webview, filter

I'm working on an app with WebView, and I have a problem with CSS3 filter property. As long as I don't use it, everything looks alright:

[image: Good-looking WebView]

But since I add `filter: invert(100%);` to `html` in CSS, text becomes blurry and hardly-readable:

[image: Bad-looking WebView]

It just looks like when you use CSS3 `filter` property, the page is rendered once at fixed resolution and then just displayed; just like there was no re-rendering after zooming the page.

I already set minimal API version to 11 and enabled hardware acceleration (like someone mentioned in another question) on whole app and it didn't work.

So, my question is: what's the reason of that WebView looking so badly? And how to improve that?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the render priority is too high so it is rendering in lower quality.

Make sure that you don't have the webview render priority set to high.